# Browser app - Shutting Down - Fatal Exception

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to run the 365 browser app on my android phone from android studio. I wanted to see how the browser app is configured so i cloned the 365 browser app from github and tried to run it in android studio. But i get the FATAL Exception:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mogoweb, PID: 18192
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeBrowserProvider: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication cannot be cast to org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5177)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication cannot be cast to org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication
                      at org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication.initCommandLine(BaseChromiumApplication.java:116)
                      at org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeBrowserProvider.onCreate(ChromeBrowserProvider.java:268)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18192 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

I am not sure which part of the code or setting is causing this problem. Could anyone pls tell me which part of the Error actually relates to the problem and how to go about solving it?

When i do search of BaseChromiumApplication.java in the project's folder, i get ChromeFullScreenManager.java as a result and that java file has the following lines:

```
import org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication;
import org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication.WindowFocusChangedListener;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication cannot be cast to org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication
                  at org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication.initCommandLine(BaseChromiumApplication.java:116)
                  at org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeBrowserProvider.onCreate(ChromeBrowserProvider.java:268)
```

See line 116 in BaseChromiumApplication.java

The variable, an object of type com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication cannot be casted to org.chromium.base.BaseChromiumApplication.
The types are unrelated. For the casting to be successful, the object type must have been created from the type, that you want to cast it into or must at least derive from that type like this:

Object
   Class_A, derived from Object
   Class_B, derived from Class_A
   Class_C, derived from Class_B

Should an object of type Class_C be created, it can later be perfectly casted into an object of type Class_A, Class_B, Class_C or Object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did a search of BaseChromiumApplication.java in the project's folder, but i don't find any files with that name.

Comment: The only result that i get is the ChromeFullScreenManager.java file and that has the two code lines that i just added to my question description.

Comment: Maybe BaseChromiumApplication.java could be stored in JAR or AAR then. But frankly, I don't know much about Android programming.